# gnuplot: plot a parametric function with *circles* (instead of with points)

Tags: gnuplot

The following gnuplot script works:

```
set parametric  
set trange [0:5]  
set xrange [0:4]  
set yrange [0:6]  
plot t+log(t+1),t*t+sin(t) title 'Parametric example' with points
```

... but this doesn't:

```
set parametric  
set trange [0:5]  
set xrange [0:4]  
set yrange [0:6]  
plot t+log(t+1),t*t+sin(t) title 'Parametric example' with circles
```

What is the correct syntax to plot with circles (rather than points), and how to set the circle diameter?

Thank you.

[EDIT]

I tried the following without success:

```
C:\gnuplot.exe  

    G N U P L O T  
    Version 4.6 patchlevel 0    last modified 2012-03-04  
    Build System: MS-Windows 32 bit  

    Copyright (C) 1986-1993, 1998, 2004, 2007-2012  
    Thomas Williams, Colin Kelley and many others  

    gnuplot home:     http://www.gnuplot.info  
    faq, bugs, etc:   type "help FAQ"  
    immediate help:   type "help"  (plot window: hit 'h')  

gnuplot changed the codepage of this console from 437 to 1252 to  
match the graph window. Some characters might only display correctly  
if you change the font to a non-raster type.  

Terminal type set to 'windows'  

gnuplot> set samples 11  

gnuplot> plot sample [t=0:2] '+' using (t+log(t+1)) : (sqrt(t)+sin(t)) : (0.05) with circles  
     undefined variable: sample  

gnuplot> plot samples [t=0:2] '+' using (t+log(t+1)) : (sqrt(t)+sin(t)) : (0.05) with circles  
     undefined variable: samples  

gnuplot> plot [t=0:2] '+' using (t+log(t+1)) : (sqrt(t)+sin(t)) : (0.05) with circles
     Pseudodata not yet implemented for polar or parametric graphs

gnuplot>
```

[EDIT2]
If I adjust the aspect ratio of the graph so that the X and Y axes are the same scale on the screen, the circles are not round.  I spent quite a bit of time searching but could not find the proper syntax to fix that.

Comment: 6:37pm EST I just edited the original post to add new information

Answer (score 0):

The `sample` keyword was introduced only with gnuplot 5. With that version your first attempt works fine:

```
set samples 11
plot sample [t=0:2] '+' using (t+log(t+1)) : (sqrt(t)+sin(t)) : (0.05) with circles
```

[image]

Comment: Jan17 9:38pm  I added a comment to the original post about the "circles" not being round.

Comment: How did you adjust the aspect ratio?

Comment: "How did you adjust the aspect ratio?"  Grab the corner of the graph and drag it until 1 unit on the X axis has the same length as 1 unit on the Y axis.

Comment: Gnuplot doesn't automatically replot when you resize. So, your initial plot is only resized and possibly distorted. Either do `replot` ( or refresh using the appropriate toolbar button after you resized the window, or  make that adjustment via terminal settings: `set terminal wxt size 800,800; set size ratio 1` or similar.

Comment: "set terminal wxt size 800,800; set size ratio 1" Thank you!  That works.